# ngx-bootstrap dropdown not opening in Angular 5 project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngx-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked for many different angular/ngx-bootstrap configurations but as I could not find any helpful answer yet, I decided to open this question.

I am trying to integrate a bootstrap dropdown component using ngx-boostrap:

**package.json**

> ```
> "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
> ```

In the head of my **index.html**

> link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"

In my **app.module.ts**

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Then I have a submodule where I try to load the dropdown :

**submodule.component.html**

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The dropdown button shows up, but nothing happens when I click it. I checked the DOM using the inspector and the content of the dropdown is still empty.

What can I do to make this dropdown work ?

**EDIT**

I have no idea how, but after playing around with the imports it ended up working.

I moved back the import of BsDropdownModule in my submodule (which was not working in the begining) and it worked. I guess I made a silly mistake by the time I opened this question but I can't find what. I leave this open in case it may help someone...

Comment: Can you please update with your dropdownComponent.ts & parent component's template file code?

Comment: @PiyushRathi I am no longer working on this project sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are properly using `selector: 'demo-dropdown-basic'` inn your component.ts and including into parent component's html like `<demo-dropdown-basic></demo-dropdown-basic>`

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I just did 3 things : adding the boostrap stylesheet to my index.html head section, including the BsDropdownModule in my App module, and then I just copied/pasted the sample in to my subcomponent html

Comment: Ok. but you should have that "component.ts" as mentioned in example with title "Single button dropdowns" here https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#single-button .

Answer (score -1):

Did you tell your button to actually show the dropdown? You need an [isOpen]="whatever", and then maybe another button, service, link, whatever where you toggle that `whatever` variable, like in the example [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns).

Comment: I don't see such a trigger in the very first example which is the one I am using.

Comment: Here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#triggers-manual

Comment: I am getting this error : `Can't bind to 'isOpen' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Comment: Another question, did you include the css files? Usually you have to add it in .angular-cli.json somewhere.

Comment: I only have `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet>"` in my **index.html** head section, is it not enough ?

Comment: That should be enough.

Comment: You can try going from the micro example that works, like this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-dropdown?file=app/app.component.html, then adding your own code bit by bit and see what breaks it.